Exclude attribute value by default in SQL Server Analysis Services Tabular Model
SQL Server Analysis Services Multidimensional Model had a functionality to exclude attribute values by default, even though they were not part of any selection. The result would be that records with this value or records with a relationship to this value would not be included in a selection, unless the attribute value would be selected explicitly.
For example you'd likely report about orders in most cases excluding a provisional order status. My aim is to prevent users from accidentally reporting results including such provisional orders.
My knowledge of Multidimensional is dated at least six years, I have no recollection of this existing in Tabular Model nor did my Google result give me anything useful. However, I would like to think this should be possible one way or another, even with a workaround.
Do you know how to accomplish this? If any relevant information is missing, please let me know.

Are you using  Multidimensional or Tabular? These are two completely different systems. One is using MDX, the other is using DAX.

@RADO I'm using Tabular, though I seem to remember such a feature with MDX from years ago. That got me wondering for Tabular.


For example you'd likely report about orders in most cases excluding a provisional order status.

There's no modeling feature for this, except perhaps row-level security where you could prevent most users from seeing provisional orders.
Normally you would handle this at the reporting layer in Power BI by setting a report-level filter on order status.

Thank you for your response. That's too bad. I have quite a few 'advanced' users using pivot tables directly onto the model, so that's a bit tricky. Will think about options with row-level security or perhaps separated measures.

You can achieve something similar to hierarchical default values using ISFILTERED dax function. When is filtered is false, you will need to hardcode default value in each measure.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/isfiltered-function-dax
